# SQLite SELECT date for a specific month

Tags: date, select, sqlite

I was using Microsoft's Jet database engine before. And, say, if I needed to select entries for a specific month I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE MONTH(`date column`)=4
```

But how do you do the same with SQLite?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE strftime('%m', date_column) = '04'
```

[Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: @ahmd0 What is strftime?Can you please elaborate the query in detail

Comment: @Eshwar Chaitanya, Follow the link in the answer.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah I have gone through the link,I have understood but that's not working for me,If you find some free time,please navigate to this link,I have struck with the retrieve issue regarding date

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725685/retrieve-month-part-from-date-saved-in-sqlite-database-table-for-displaying-mont

Comment: Can you help this is not working for me my code is below:   "SELECT * FROM USER_DATA  where strftime('%m', created_date) ='04'"; "created_date"->field name . In database my date format is "MM-dd-yyyy"

Comment: I just have one question, would it work if I just state "x" instead of "0x"? Is the prefix 0 necessary? Thank you!

Comment: @Neon Warge, `= '4'` is quite different than `= '04'`

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE strftime('%m', `date column`) = '04'
```

[***sqlite date&time functions***](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Haha. I knew it was simple. Thanks!