# Sqlite3 search column by providing Year and month

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

The Following function create a table in sqlite3:

```
def create_table(mycursor):
     mycursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ch_details(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
          ch_id TEXT, ch_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, ch_no TEXT, cli TEXT, vhs_no TEXT, f_lo TEXT,
          t_lo TEXT, qty REAL, adv REAL DEFAULT 0 , oth_de REAL DEFAULT 0, ch_amt REAL DEFAULT 0, mem_id TEXT,
          UNIQUE(ch_id));''')
```

which stores my date in Datetime in ch_date column however when
i try to get the last row of ch_id column in this table stored by providing specific month/year using the following code:

```
def gen_chid():
    dt, mt, yr = cal_gen.get().split("/")
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database/u_data.vita')
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT ch_id FROM ch_details WHERE strftime('%Y%m', ch_date)",yr, mt)
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
```

The code gets this error:

```
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The can_gen.get() gets the date from entry box in "07/07/2021" string format

I have also checked this stack answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669596/10401287) but did not get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's datetime functions like `strftime()` work only if the datetime values that are passed to them have the format `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates or `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` for datetimes.
If you stored the dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` then the only way to extract the date parts like day, month or year is by treating the date as a string and use string functions like `SUBSTR()`:

```
def gen_chid():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database/u_data.vita')
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """
    SELECT ch_id 
    FROM ch_details 
    WHERE SUBSTR(ch_date, 4) = ?
    """
    mycursor.execute(sql, (cal_gen.get()[3:],))
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
```

Here `SUBSTR(ch_date, 4)` extracts the month/year part in the format `MM/YYYY` and it is compared to the substring returned from `cal_gen.get()` after the 3d char which is passed to `execute()` as the only member of a list.

Comment: As per your suggestion i changed my date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` and changed the code of `mycursor.execute(sql, (cal_gen.get()[:-3],))` now what changes need to be applied in `SUBSTR(ch_date, 4)` part.

Comment: @ScrappyCoco did you also change `cal_gen.get()` to return the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: yes i have change it to `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Comment: @ScrappyCoco Then the query should be: `SELECT ch_id FROM ch_details WHERE SUBSTR(ch_date, 1, 7) = ?` (the first 7 chars of the date provide year and month like `'2021-07'`) and then call `mycursor.execute(sql, (cal_gen.get()[0:7],))`

Comment: @ScrappyCoco or with strftime: `SELECT ch_id FROM ch_details WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', ch_date) = ?`